# Angular2 , get specific element from Array of Arrays using NgFor

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

My goal is to get the array of objects of any index from the services array of arrays, and cycle through that array of objects through *ngFor

FILE.TS

```
services:  Array<Servizio[]> = [];
```

FILE.HTML this is what I'd like to be able to do , but nothing shows in my list

```
  <li *ngFor="let servizio of services[0]"> 
                                <a href="#">{{servizio.name}}</a>
                            </li>
```

Answer (score 1):

ngFor works on an array, you are trying to use over first element of the array which is an object, you should do

```
 <li *ngFor="let servizio of services"> 
      <a href="#">{{servizio.name}}</a>
 </li>
```

Answer (score 1):

I post the solution to my problem in case it's helpful to anyone :

```
<ul class="nav nav-list">
                                <span *ngFor="let servizio of services; let idx = index">
                                    <span *ngIf="idx  === 2">
                                        <li *ngFor="let ser of servizio">
                                            <a href="#">{{ser.name}}</a>

                                        </li>
                                    </span>
                                </span>
                            </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :

**my example :**

template

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let servizio of services[0]?.subMenuItem"> 
        <a href="#">{{servizio.name}}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

typescript :

```
services: Array<any[]> = [{
    "name": "xyz",
    "subMenuItem": [{
        "name": "abc"
    }, {
        "name": "cde"
    }],
    "icon": "home"
}, {
    "name": "pqr",
    "subMenuItem": [{
        "name": "abc"
    }, {
        "name": "cde"
    }],
    "icon": "home"
}];
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer , what I'm trying to do is to access through *ngFor the first array of objects of the type  Servizio from the services array and cycle through the elements of that array , any idea on how to ?

Comment: can you provide example data for services ?